# getting external route instance from a controller in ember

Tags: ember.js

I want to set some property in an external router from a controller. Is there a way to do that?
Currently when I try :

```
AS.AnalyticsIndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ["analyticsRunsIndex"],
    engagements: null,
    exercises: null,
    exerciseRuns: null,
    selectedExercise: null,
    selectedExerciseRun: null,
    selectedEngagement: null,
    actions: {
        goToAnalyticsRuns: function () {
            if (this.get('selectedExerciseRun.id')) {
                this.get('controllers.analyticsRunsIndex').get('target').set('exerciseRunId', this.get('selectedExerciseRun.id'));

            }
        }
    }
.......
```

the "this.get('controllers.analyticsRunsIndex').get('target')" returns main router at the moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot recall why I wanted to do things this way, but it seems like there is no direct way to access external route. What I could have done was accessed the external router via the controller itself like:

```
AS.AnalyticsRunsIndex = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions:{
        do: function(something){
            this.get('target').set('exerciseRunId', something);
        }
    }
});
```

And in AnalyticsIndexController :

```
 actions: {
    goToAnalyticsRuns: function () {
        if (this.get('selectedExerciseRun.id')) {
            this.get('controllers.analyticsRunsIndex').send('do',this.get('selectedExerciseRun.id'));

        }
    }
}
```

I think what I was trying to do might not have been the "Ember" way of doing things. So if someone else is trying to solve similar problem, may be its better to take closer look and see if there is better way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to do this in Ember now is with [`getOwner`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/functions/@ember%2Fapplication/getOwner).

For example, to send an action to your application route:

```js
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { action } from '@ember/object'; // https://github.com/pzuraq/ember-decorators-polyfill
import { getOwner } from '@ember/application';

export default class MyTopLevelComponent extends Component {
    @action
    closeModal() {
      getOwner(this).lookup('route:application').send('closeModal');
    }
});
```